# Bootstrap 4 columns break uneven

Tags: bootstrap-4

Thank you for taking time to help.

I am using Bootsrap 4. But, the grid system is really different from Bootsrap 3, and I can't tell if my layout looks strange because of an error in my html code or, if this is intentional and how Bootsrap 4 is supposed to work. Can you please take a look at my html below and confirm?

I am trying to make a row with five equal columns. The columns are responsive, and should collapse on small and extra small screens:

**HTML:**

```
<div class="container">
  <div class="row test">

    <!-- col 1 -->
    <div class="col-lg col-md col-sm-12 col-xs-12">
      Stuff
    </div>

    <!-- col 2 -->
    <div class="col-lg col-md col-sm-12 col-xs-12">
      Stuff
    </div>

    <!-- col 3 -->
    <div class="col-lg col-md col-sm-12 col-xs-12">
      Stuff
    </div>

    <!-- col 4 -->
    <div class="col-lg col-md col-sm-12 col-xs-12">
      Stuff
    </div>

    <!-- col 5 -->
    <div class="col-lg col-md col-sm-12 col-xs-12">
      Stuff
    </div>

  </div><!-- end row -->
</div><!-- end container -->
```

The problem happens when I add content... Watch the layout break and columns look all weird. See example, [here](https://codepen.io/matie/pen/bxENGW?editors=1100).

What am I doing wrong? Is this how Bootsrap 4 is supposed to work?

Ideally, the columns collapse equally, not one more column collpasing faster than the other columns, which is happening now.

Again, what am I doing wrong?

Thank you,

- Matie

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You only need to use `col-sm` which means equal width on small and up.
The content of your columns is making the row wrap because the content is too wide for the column (overflowing). Use `flex-sm-nowrap` to prevent the columns from wrapping before the xs breakpoint.

https://codepen.io/anon/pen/Kxzrqd?editors=1100

```
<div class="container">
  <div class="row flex-sm-nowrap">

    <!-- col 1 -->
    <div class="col-sm">
      Stuff
    </div>

    <!-- col 2 -->
    <div class="col-sm">
      Stuff
    </div>

    <!-- col 3 -->
    <div class="col-sm">
      Stuff
    </div>

    <!-- col 4 -->
    <div class="col-sm">
      Stuff
    </div>

    <!-- col 5 -->
    <div class="col-sm">
      Stuff
    </div>

  </div><!-- end row -->
</div><!-- end container -->
```

You may want to use `col-md` instead because the content doesn't fit inside the columns.

Note: `-xs` is no longer used in Bootstrap 4.